# Render a razor view loop in vue.js

Tags: c#, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use a for loop to render out html along with text at the same time.

```
 <div id="container">
     <ul>
        <li v-for="item in itemDetails" :id="item.id">{{ item.result }}</li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 new Vue({
   el: "#container",
   data: {
      itemDetails: [
          { id: "firstId", result: "@Model.First" },
          { id: "secondId", result: '@foreach(var newItem in @Model.List)
              if(newItem.Index == Model.ListId)
              {
                  <option value="newItem.Index" selected>@newItem.Value</option>
              }
              else
              {
                  <option value="newItem.Index">@newItem.Value</option>
              }
           '
          }
      ]
   }
 });
```

The first item comes in fine because it's just text but if I need to render HTML as the 2nd result, it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to do both at same time. The second item is rendering a select dropdown with the item that it equals being selected.

Comment: i think you should request that model using axios and show it using vue js

Comment: There isn't a way to integrate the Model thats on the page currently? I need to make another call using axios to do this?

Comment: You can create a component for an individual item and place that component inside your for loop with conditions.

Comment: So I would have to create a new component each time I need to do this then?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `@Model` from within JavaScript, turn your `@Model` into JSON, and pass that into your `data` property.  You do that by using `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`.  Then make a computed property based on that.

```
data: { 
    itemModel: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
},
computed: {
    itemDetails() {
        return this.itemModel.map(x => /* whatever you want to do here . . . */);
    }
}
```